# How determine an element's location in the HStack or VStack after rendering

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view like this:

```
ZStack {
    LottieView() // it is a lighting animation
    VStack { // content
        Text("Title")
        Image("icon")
        Text("Subtitle")
    }
}
```

Please let me clarify the following: The lighting animation needs to be displayed at the center of the `icon`, based on my criteria. However, if the 'text' title has just one or two lines, the `icon` will slightly shift up or down. To resolve this issue, we can adjust the position of the `LottieView` `icon` after it is rendered. I am not entirely certain if this solution will work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the .offset and .position modifer.

Comment: Instead of trying to determine where the icon is, maybe you could remove the `ZStack` and move the `LottieView` into a `.background` modifier on the `Image`.